# Clustering Two Variables With Disease Information

Tags: clustering, model, predictor, graph-theory

I was proposed a problem and I am not quite sure how to go about it. The problem is I want to find a relationship between two variables. For the simplified case there are only two variables, lets say Diabetes and Congestive Heart Failure. Each variables has a $0$ or a $1$, if you do not have the disease or if you do, respectively.

This was presented to me as a clustering problem. We can see how the clusters form and see which disease is most dominant or just how they relate to each other. My assumption is there would be 4 clusters, cluster 1 is people who have neither, cluster two is people with Diabets, cluster 3 is people with Congestive Heart Failure and cluster 4 is people who have both.

My questions are:

1. Is this a valid way to determine a relationship between the variables?
2. How would I create the affinity matrix?
3. How would I visualize the clusters?

Has anyone has experience with this type of modeling? Any ideas outside of clustering would be appreciated! Any insight or help or references would be highly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: How many variables do you actually have? If you have dozens, then you might consider categorical clustering algorithms, or a latent class model. With only two variables, then Tamas' answer below is great.

Comment: As of right now I actually only have these two. I will definitely look into what you suggested as I get more variables. Thank you!

Comment: @ ahfoss - Thinking about this a little more there is one extra variable I might add but it would be a cost estimate from hospital visits and I'd want to find a relationship between these three variables.

Comment: Are you interested in predicting some variables based on others? Are you interested in discovering groups of similar patients? Your specific goals make all the difference in identifying appropriate methods.

Comment: For three variables, calculating the contingency table still works, but for more variables (especially if you have 5, 10, or even more) things get complicated...

Comment: @ ahfoss - I am interested in predicting costs based on that information and also yes grouping similar patients together.

Comment: If cost is a continuous variable, then you might simply use linear regression, with two explanatory variables, namely DM and CHF (as dummy variables). You might also consider adding their interaction, i.e. DM * CHF. If cost is markedly skewed (which is quite typical) you might also experiment with using logCost as the independent variable instead of Cost.

Comment: Thank you again for the insight! When I was asked this question I originally thought along the lines of statistics (as far as linear regression). It was when I was asked to think about the problem non-parametrically that threw me off. Thank you again.

Comment: @RDizzl3 : Again: you're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that this is not a clustering problem in the [usual sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) of the word.

The ''clusters'' what you described are actually called [contingency table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) of Diabetes and CHF. To answer your first question, the calculation of this table is surely the first step towards any analysis, as no information is lost in this case if you convert your database to a contingency table. In R you can simply do it (of course by using the variable names of your database ) by

```
DmChfTab <- table( Database$DM, Database$CHF )
DmChfTab
```

The real question is how to analyze this table. If you are interested in the relationship of diabetes and CHF, you need a measure of association (in statistical terms), of which [there are many](http://uregina.ca/~gingrich/ch11a.pdf). In this case, Pearson $\chi^2$-test for independence, [$\phi$-coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient), contingency coefficient and [Cramer's V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V) might be of your interest. You can calculate these in R with

```
assocstats( DmChfTab )
```

Note that `assocstats` requires the package `vcd`.

As for your second question, I don't know what do you mean by ''affinity matrix'', it's perhaps just the same as contingency table (as a matrix).

Finally, to visualize the contingency table, you might consider

```
mosaic( DmChfTab )
```

(also from `vcd`) or, as a more advanced tool, `assoc( DmChfTab )` (also from `vcd`).

Comment: Thank you Tamas for your insight. This was a question that I was asked and the person who asked said to think of it as a clustering problem. I myself was not exactly sure how to tackle it. You have listed things that I will for sure look into! Thank you!

Comment: @RDizzl3 : You're welcome!